# How to use SUM() with hasMany result from Model in Laravel 5.6

Tags: eloquent

I Try to Get result using this Model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use DB;
class Customer_Bones extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'customer_bones';
  protected $primaryKey = 'customer_bones_id';
  protected $fillable = array(
    'created_at',
    'deleted',
    'system_user',
    'customer_id',
    'bones_id'
);
public $timestamps = false;

public function getBonusCustomers(){

    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Bonus_Item','customer_bones_id');

}

public function getCustomer(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Customer','customer_id');
}
}
```

My Controller function is this

```
return Customer_Bones::with(array(
'getCustomer' => function($query)
{
  $query->select('customer_name','customer_id');
},
'getBonusCustomers' => function($query)
{
  $query->select(DB::raw('sum(bonus_quantity) as bonusQuantity'));
}))
->get();
```

I want to get sum of the `bonus_quantity` column that belongs to `Bonus_Item` Table with `customer_name` from `customer` table and some other details from `customer_bones` table. I had Tried above method but `bonusQuantity` return me null.

Can I use `DB::raw('sum(bonus_quantity) as bonusQuantity')` inside the `select clause` like above to get summation of `bonus_quantity` column, along with other details or is there any other method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `withCount` with raw expression in callback to get the required sum like

```
Customer_Bones::with(['getCustomer' => function($query){
                                          $query->select('customer_name','customer_id');
                                       }
])->withCount(['getBonusCustomers as bonusQuantity' => function($query) {
                                                            $query->select(DB::raw('SUM(bonus_quantity)'));
                                                        }
])->get();
```

Or you could define a new mapping in your model which returns sum per `customer_bones_id`

```
public function getBonusCustomersSum(){

    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Bonus_Item','customer_bones_id')
                ->select('customer_bones_id',DB::raw('sum(bonus_quantity) as bonusQuantity'))
                ->groupBy('customer_bones_id');
}

Customer_Bones::with(['getCustomer' => function($query){
                                          $query->select('customer_name','customer_id');
                                       }
, 'getBonusCustomersSum'])
->get();
```

[Laravel use multiple where and sum in single clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51226415/laravel-use-multiple-where-and-sum-in-single-clause)

Comment: @Khalid first method work like charm with some edit.  Thank you very much. But second method i already tried, but result is null.

Comment: This line `$query->select(DB::raw('SUM(bonus_quantity)'));` Helped :)