# Best Way to Count Record Many Table - Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I want to display the number of records from several tables at once in one view.
I've tried it using eloquent count.

```
public function index(){
    $order = Order::count();
    $owner = Owner::count();
    $room = Room::count();
    $member = Transaction::where([
        ['status', 'waiting'],
        ['type', 1]
        ])->count();

    $highlight = Transaction::where([
        ['status', 'waiting'],
        ['type', 2]
        ])->count();


    return view('admin.index', [
        'order' => $order,
        'owner' => $owner,
        'room' => $room,
        'member' => $member,
        'highlight' => $highlight
    ]);
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: a better way compared to what?

Comment: For transactions count you could get it in a single query using conditional sum [Laravel use multiple where and sum in single clause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51455791/853360)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [view-composers](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#view-composers). But this is not better, just different. I mean you have to query anyway, so why do you think there should be a better way?

Comment: Thanks before. I just think there is a better query approach. Suppose a raw query @Flo

Comment: Imho your approach is fine. You can compare queries like this:

`DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
User::count();
dd(DB::getQueryLog());` 
Like this you also get the query time and the query that was executed.